# What is [AssertionCredentials] parameter in BigQuery library and how to get it?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-oauth

[BigQuery-Python](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python) is a small python package that provides functions to interact with GCP's BigQuery. To use it one needs to first instantiate a client object. The documentation for the function [get_client() states](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python/blob/master/bigquery/client.py#L61) that

```
def get_client(project_id=None, credentials=None,
               service_url=None, service_account=None,
               private_key=None, private_key_file=None,
               json_key=None, json_key_file=None,
               readonly=True, swallow_results=True,
               num_retries=0):
    """Return a singleton instance of BigQueryClient. Either
    AssertionCredentials or a service account and private key combination need
    to be provided in order to authenticate requests to BigQuery.
    Parameters
    ----------
    project_id : str, optional
        The BigQuery project id, required unless json_key or json_key_file is
        provided.
    credentials : oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, optional
        AssertionCredentials instance to authenticate requests to BigQuery
        (optional, must provide `service_account` and (`private_key` or
        `private_key_file`) or (`json_key` or `json_key_file`) if not included
```

Can someone explain to me what is the credentials parameter is and how to use it properly?

Comment: If you don't provide the credential, the ADC mechanism will get it automatically. It's your best option if you run your script on Google Cloud environment or on your personal computer. Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc

Comment: for this 3rd party library it doesn't seem to get it automatically

Comment: Try this: `import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials parameter in the case of that library refers to means of authenticating with GCP.

The developer has provided [examples in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating).

You must first [create your service account in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating). Then you can download a JSON key for that service account which you use in authenticating with the service. E.g.

```
# JSON key provided by Google
json_key = 'key.json'
 
client = get_client(json_key_file=json_key, readonly=True)
```

It should be noted that this is a third-party library and it seems to require setting up a service account and downloading credentials but this isn't considered a best practice. You should [use attached service accounts wherever possible](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-service-accounts#use-attached-service-accounts). These will use Application Default Credentials which are better from a management and security point of view.